# Infinite Scroll is loading the same last value always

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I managed to retrieve the data from firebase, implementing an infinite scroll... is working  right but when i scroll till end, is loading the same last values always..
Tried to change the .limitToLast to .startAt but there is no difference.

```
private void isScrollCompleted() {
                if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                        && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    /** To do code here*/
                    oldestPostId = oldDummy;
                    Query query = SearchRef.orderByKey();
                   if (oldestPostId != null) {
                        query = query.limitToLast(limitToLast).endAt(oldestPostId);
                   }
                    dataList.clear();
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Query ordenar = mDatabase.child("Off-Topic").orderByChild("countthreads");
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                MessageThread messageThread = child.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                                if (messageThread != null) {
                                    oldestPostId = child.getKey();
                                    oldestPostidScrollList.add(child.getKey());
                                    if (oldestPostidScrollList.size() > m) {
                                        String myIdss = oldestPostidScrollList.get(m);
                                        oldDummy = myIdss;
                                    }
                                    messageThread.thread_id = child.getKey();
                                }

                                dataList.add(messageThread);
                                if (dataList.size() == 5) {
                                    Collections.reverse(dataList);
                                    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.size(); j++) {
                                        threadsList.add(dataList.get(j));
                                    }
                                    threadsAdapter = new ThreadsAdapter(ThreadsActivity.this, R.layout.threads_listview,
                                            threadsList, tryList, ThreadsActivity.this, ordenar);
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }, 1000);
                                    threadsListView.setSelection(scrollTO);
                                } else {
                                    if (lastValueCalled) {
                                        lastValueCalled = true;
                                        for (int j = 0; j < dataList.size(); j++) {
                                            threadsList.add(dataList.get(j));
                                        }
                                        scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            scrollTO = scrollTO + 10;
                            int x = tryList.size();
                            int temp = x - m;
                            int count = temp - 10;
                            if (count > 10 && temp > 10) {
                                m = m + 10;
                            } else if (nCalled) {
                                Log.e("called", "data is over");
                            } else {
                                lastValueCalled = true;
                                if (lastValueCalled) {
                                    nCalled = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
```

Also checked the log and is giving the result "data is over" but continues doing the same thing always. Any clue?

Comment: If you try to hardcode the value from which it should start the second time, does it behave the same?

Comment: nope, it change the result but continues giving the same issue